# How should I provide feedback to a Documentation example?

Tags: support, documentation

I've seen a lot of examples where I would personally do it slightly different, either coding wise or editorially (for example, a lot of examples cover a couple of topics and could be split).

How do I provide such feedback, without getting into a editing war?

Comment: What's wrong with the current "Proposed Changes"?

Comment: "Proposed Changes" doesn't say "have you tried..." Or "did you consider..."; it says " you should have done it like..."

Comment: Do you accept the answer below? So you should accept it or clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

In the case where an Example should be split into multiple Examples, just edit the original Example and split it up into two (or more) Examples. Make sure each Example stands on its own without needing to read the other Examples you just split. Other users will approve your edit.

If the Example works but is merely not how you would do it, I'd say leave it. Make a similar Example with your implementation. Good examples will be upvoted, and poor ones won't, so just like Answers to Questions, the best ones will end up at the top and the worst ones at the bottom.

If the Example doesn't work, edit it to correct it, so that it does work. Again, other users will approve your edit.

Comment: Can see that turning into a vicious circle during review process when people see duplication and reject the split items which are new without recognizing the bigger picture. Agree with splitting but would help to be able to identify it clearly as a split  while it is being reviewed

Comment: @charlietfl When you edit multiple items in a topic (e.g. editing one Example and adding another), it all appears as one set of changes, not one change per item. The entire change set is reviewed and approved/rejected as a whole. So the reviewers will be able to see that one Example is being split into two.

Comment: Perhaps but have my doubts when it comes to some "robo reviewers" paying close enough attention. Already see a lot of people that are not detail oriented playing around in documentation

Comment: @Martin Thanks; it wasn't clear to me that I would be able to edit multiple examples at once, until I did a review of someone that had done just that